# Remove background noise from recording

Tags: fft, filters, noise

I have a sample speech recording with background noise. I managed to extract part of the noise signal, and put the noise and the contaminated signal in the same plot.
[image]

I have done fft-analysis on both speech and noise, and since their frequency bands with centralized power are close to each other, I cannot simply apply a bandpass filter. Is there another way to remove the noise from the speech signal with knowledge of the noise itself? (No, subtraction does not work)

Comment: Obviously, subtracting can only work for things you *know* – noise, by nature, is random.

Comment: Do you mean by knowledge of the noise?  You said "extract part of the noise signal": where, and how?

Comment: @LaurentDuval There're some parts of the original speech where the person is not talking, so there's only background noise. I extracted that part and extended it to the same length of the original signal.

Comment: @F. Bai You can check the noise properties on these parts. You might have a deterministic and a random parts, to help you do further processing

Comment: Your question has beeen answered. Do not hesitate to vote for the useful ones and accept the most suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal seems non-stationary, at least less stationary than the noise, and the noise is of relatively lower amplitude. Hence, a class of methods resides in performing one or several non-stationary transformations (time-frequency, time-scale, or  spectrograms and wavelets). They can concentrate useful signals on a little amount of coefficients. Then, thresholding or shrinkage techniques, reducing low-coefficients and preserving higher ones can be interesting.

Free softwares like audacity have build-in functions. For more techniques, you can check for instance:

- [VOICEBOX: Speech Processing Toolbox for MATLAB](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/voicebox.html), esp. Spectral noise subtraction.

More advanced techniques, termed "source separation", are for instance described by:

- [FASST: Flexible Audio Source Separation Toolbox](http://bass-db.gforge.inria.fr/fasst/)

Answer (score 0):

Programs such as Adobe Audition ([video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZjlS0tD-Wg)) and Izotope RX ([video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WzBjEd6JVE)) are able to reduce noise by a two-step process that goes roughly like this:

1. Spectrally profile the noise in non-voiced segments of the audio. You can select a suitable segment by yourself. I don't know the details of what kind of statistics are collected at this step.
2. In the complete audio, reduce the magnitude of the frequency bins depending on the noise profile. I don't know the details of this step either.

Such processing creates artifacts and the programs use different tricks such as spectral smoothing to reduce them. Different material may benefit from using a different FFT size.